# Cookies not getting printed

Tags: javascript, cookies

I am trying to read 3 cookies and then print their values, but for some reason  the page keeps loading indefinitely, the cookies get printed though but the page keeps loading. I am not much well versed with javascript so dont know why this is happening. I am posting my code below may be that will help. By the way all 3 cookies are there and have proper values, I have checked using a php script which can read their values just fine.

```
<html>
<head>
<script>

var userRPM = true;
var userRWebcam = false;
var userEntryExitSFX = true;
var userNewMessageSFX = true;
var userSFX = true; 
/*
* read cookie
*
*/

function readCookie(name)
{
    var nameEQ = name + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++)
    {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
        if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
    }

    return null;
}

/*
* get cookie
*
*/

var gotCookie1 = readCookie('myTextStyle');
var gotCookie2 = readCookie('myOptions');

function getCookie()
{
    if(gotCookie1)
    {
        gotCookie = decodeURI(gotCookie1).split("|");

        mBold = gotCookie[0];
        mItalic = gotCookie[1];
        mUnderline = gotCookie[2];
        textColor = gotCookie[3];
        textSize = gotCookie[4];
        textFamily = gotCookie[5];
    }

    if(gotCookie2)
    {
        gotCookie = decodeURI(gotCookie2).split("|");

        userRPM = gotCookie[0];
        userRWebcam = gotCookie[1];
        userEntryExitSFX = gotCookie[2];
        userNewMessageSFX = gotCookie[3];
        userSFX = gotCookie[4];
    }
document.write('<p>colour: ' + textColor + '<br>textFamily: ' + textFamily + '<br>textSize: ' + textSize + '</p>');


}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<button onclick="getCookie()">Print cookies</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I only see 2 cookies.

Comment: @Shawn31313 you can visit www.techbreeze.in/tchat/test.html to find the cookies that are getting printed

Comment: No cookies are printed. But thats because they were never set. I don't really see the issue here.